# Complex Query over Rest API in Cloud FireStore

Tags: rest, google-cloud-firestore

How to pass complex get query parameters such as where order etc into `GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/{name=projects/*/databases/*/documents/*/**}`([firestore docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/get)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order and limit data in a Cloud Firestore query after using the [Get Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) method like this:

```
myDinoRef.where("type", "==", "TREX").orderBy("size", "desc").limit(2)
```

This will return all TRex Dinos and order by descending "size". It will also limit the result set to two rows.

[Google's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) is pretty good and ever evolving. It's also important to point out that the Cloud Firestore is still in beta (as of today)